# How to add Interactive Markers in URDF robot model

Tags: rviz, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the interactive markers tutorial, creation of the markers is made by creating simple objects (CUBES) in server  Interactive server program. How add interactive markers to robot saved as urdf model?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210999/how-to-add-interactive-markers-in-urdf-robot-model./) by [mikioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/22732/mikioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot describe interactive markers in the URDF, but when you're creating the interactive marker you can specify a link in the tf tree to which it is attached, and that link is described in the URDF.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0